# Meteor spacebars ошибки рендеринга массива

Tags: meteor

Есть код в html файле:

```
    {{#each answer in question.answers}}
                    <div id="answer-option-wrapper-{{randomId}}" class="col-md-12 question-answer-option--wrapper">
                        <div class="col-md-12 question-answer-option">
                            <input class="col-md-1" style="margin-top: 0.5em;" name="answer" type="{{radioOrCheckbox question}}">
                            <input id="{{randomId}}" type="text" placeholder="Вариант ответа" class="col-md-10 question-field-answer" style="" value="{{answer}}">

                            <div class="col-md-1 delete-answer-option" style=""><i style="padding:2px"
                                                                                                                                         class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash"
                                                                                                                                         aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                {{/each}}
```

Я использовал id на всякий случай. `question.answers` - это массив. Есть обработчик `change .question-field-answer`, который обновляет это значение в БД. DOM напрямую не изменяется.

Проблема в том, что при одинаковых значениях `answers`, если изменить текст в input, этот текст появляется в соседнем input. Иногда сверху, иногда снизу. В самой `mongo` коллекции все нормально обновляется. Я подозреваю, что `meteor` использует значение строки как ключ (почему не использует индекс в массиве?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я и предполагал, проблема в рендеринге строк. Spacebars почему-то различает строки по значению, а не по индексу в массиве. [Вот документация](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#Reactivity-Model-for-Each)

Решение проблемы - использовать объекты. Объкты различаются по ключу `_id` или по индексу в массиве.

Сейчас код выглядит вот так:

```
{{#each answer in question.answers}}
                                <div class="col-md-12 question-answer-option--wrapper">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 question-correct-answer-option {{successClass answer}}"
                                             data-id="{{answer._id}}">
                                        <input id="{{answer._id}}" class="col-md-1 correct-answer-checkbox" style="margin-top: 0.5em;"
                                                     name="answer"
                                                     type="{{radioOrCheckbox question}}" {{isChecked answer.correct true}}>
                                        <label for="{{answer._id}}" class="col-md-11 question-correct-answer">
                                            {{answer.text}}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            {{/each}}
```